# Batch copy to multiple directories

Tags: shell, cp, xargs

I have about 9000 files in a directory and I want to mv  them into 90 files in 100 directories by filename order, ignoring any remainder. In [Copy multiple files from filename X to filename Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11418/copy-multiple-files-from-filename-x-to-filename-y), [Caleb](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/1925/caleb) wrote in a [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11418/copy-multiple-files-from-filename-x-to-filename-y#comment15178_11420):

> If the object is just to batch them, there is a MUCH easier way! `ls | xargs -iX -n20 cp X target_folder/` would run cp on files in batches of 20 until they were all done.

So based off of using xargs, how could I switch the target_folder to create a new folder and loop the command 100 times?

Comment: U&L is a wiki, not a message board: please rewrite your question as a question, removing the reference to a community member and including a link to the post your reference. See [the FAQ for help on asking questions](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask)

Answer (score 2):

In `bash`, try the following code :

```
#!/bin/bash

c=0

for f; do
    if ! ((c % 100)); then
        folder=folder_$(printf "%03d\n" $c)
        mkdir -p $folder
    fi

    [[ -d "$f" ]] || mv "$f" "$folder"
    ((c++))
done
```

Run the script like that :

```
./script.bash *
```

Answer (score 1):

That command doesn't look close to what you're trying to do. `xargs` can help, but it's cumbersome to use unless you know your file names do not contain any whitespace or quoting character. Here's a shell loop that dispatches files into newly-created subdirectories, 90 per directory.

```
set -- *
# Set args to "$1" "$2" ... "$90"
i=1 args=
while [ $i -le 90 ]; do
  slice="$slice \"\${$i}\""
  i=$((i+1))
done
# Move files 90 at a time
i=0
while [ $# -ge 90 ]; do
  mkdir part$i
  eval "mv $slice part$i"
  shift 90
done
# 0 to 89 files remain in the current directory
```

Comment: `xargs` also has an option `-0` which turns off the whitespace and quote processing.   But I agree this kind of script is the best approach.

Comment: @Gilles There's an error in the script: `$slice` should be `$args`

Answer (score 0):

`parallel` supports running multiple commands with `\;` and `{#}` is the sequence number:

```
ls|parallel -n90 mkdir {#}\;mv {} {#}
```

Or if the filenames don't contain spaces, quotes, or backslashes:

```
i=1;while read l;do mkdir $i;mv $l $((i++));done< <(ls|xargs -n90)
```